# How to use class Object in out parameter with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I was trying to Mock some some functionality of my Services. The code goes like this.

```
public interface IObj {
       public bool anotherMethod(string input, out string responseString);
}

public class SomeClass {
      public bool SomeMethod(string input, out IObj outputObj) {
             // some logic
             if (logic is correct) {
                  outputObj = // object of IObj
                  return true;
             }
             outputObj = null;
             return false;
       }
}

public class Service {
       public void executingMethod(){
               if (this.someClassObj.SomeMethod(this.inputString, out outputObj) {
                   if (outputObj.anotherMethod(this.anotherInputString, out responseString) 
                    {
                        // some business logic
                    }

               }
       }

}
```

Now i want to Mock the method `executingMethod` behaviour vai UnitTest using Moq and xUnit.
But while mocking I am getting issue with `out` parameter. In this way I am trying to mock the behaviour.

```
[Fact]
public void MockingMethod(){
       // Arrange
       Mock<SomeClass> mockSomeClass = new Mock<SomeClass>();
       Mock<IObj> mockIObj = new Mock<IObj>();
       string mockedResponse = "someResponse";

       // here i am getting the issue, as out is expecting actual object not mocked object.
       mockSomeClass.Setup(s => s.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<string>(), out mockIObj).Returns(true);
       mockIObj.Setup(s => s.anotherMethod(It.IsAny<string(), out mockedResponse).Returns(true);

}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. TIA.

I tried to use as suggested by @Roman as well.
`mockSomeClass.Setup(s => s.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<string>(), out mockIObj.Object).Returns(true);`

but it is throwing this error -> "A property or indexer may not be passed as out or ref parameter"

Answer (score 0):

Try “mockIObj.Object” . This should pass in the mocked object rather than the mocked instance

Comment: thanks for the reply @scottdavidwalker can't use "mockObj.Object" -> "A property or indexer may not be passed as out or ref parameter"

Comment: Could you try setting it up as an Is.Any and then using a callback to get the value?

Comment: `Is.Any` is not assignable value for 'ref' and 'out' parameters. let me know if i missunderstood anything.@scottdavidwalker

Answer (score 0):

I Found other way to resolve this issue.
This method  `public bool SomeMethod(string input, out IObj outputObj)`
was calling one another method like this  `public bool oneAnotherMethod(string input, out string outputResponse)` mocking this method resolve the issue.

I was not knowing that mocking internal calls can propagate above the calling chain.

Thanks for all the help.